# Can someone tell any of the applications running on ROS Kinetic without using any external hardware devices?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know which applications/programs that can be run on the ROS Kinetic running on Ubuntu 16.04 without using any external devices like camera,sensors or others.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253565/can-someone-tell-any-of-the-applications-running-on-ros-kinetic-without-using-any-external-hardware-devices-?/) by [a443](https://answers.ros.org/users/29219/a443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2017-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pretty much everything this is released in combination with a simulation, like gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [a443](https://answers.ros.org/users/29219/a443/) on 2017-02-02**:
Thanks Mig